# Where is the location of Naraka, the abode of Yama?

Tags: puranas, lokas, hell

Hindu scriptures often refer to hell-like place as Naraka. I want to know whether this place is located inside or the outside of the earth.

I have read somewhere that it is located on the same plane as pitra-loka but is separated by some boundary, but that would mean Yama rules the pitra-loka too, but that's not true since Yama rules the Yama-loka (which contains the Naraka)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where is Naraka's Location?

https://www.thehinduportal.com/2017/08/what-is-naraka-hell-and-where-it-located.html

> The Bhagavata Purana describes Naraka as beneath the earth: between the seven realms of the underworld (Patala) and the Garbhodaka Ocean, which is the bottom of the universe. It is located in the South of the universe. Pitrloka, where the dead ancestors (Pitrs) headed by Agniṣvāttā reside, is also located in this region. Yama, the Lord of Naraka, resides in this realm with his assistants. The Devi Bhagavata Purana mentions that Naraka is the southern part of the universe, below the earth but above Patala. The Vishnu Purana mentions that it is located below the cosmic waters at the bottom of the universe. The Hindu epics to agree that Naraka is located in the South, the direction which is governed by Yama and is often associated with Death. Pitrloka is considered as the capital of Yama, from where Yama

Comment: I didn't know Pitrloka too is inside the earth ! Thanks

Comment: If you like the answer, then you can vote up for it